# You can say cometh/commeth and you can say hast come but not hast cometh, why?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Why is it wrong to say/write

> hast cometh

and it's perfectly fine to say

> hast come?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you think it *should* be fine to say \*"hast cometh" (present-day \*"[you] have comes")  instead of "hast come" ("[you] have come"). Do you understand what the different forms mean?

Comment: Would you say “have comes” in regular English? Presumably not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, yeah that is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks. To convert it to common English terms I'm acquainted with.
"Have comes" definitely doesn't make sense... I thought hast could work as 'has' and cometh could replace 'come'.

Comment: @ruakh, when you don't use the archaic form I understand perfectly. Is there any way I could learn about the proper archaic form of verbs and such? Thanks.

Comment: I guess what confused me was that come is the same in v3 and also I mixed hath with hast cause I'm not acquainted with archaic English at all.

Comment: @wolfdawn _Hast_ and _hath_ are both present tense (2nd sg and 3rd sg), just like _comest_ and _cometh_ are. Generally, in these archaic forms, the 2nd sg ends in _-st_, 3rd sg in _-th_; the rest are the same, also the past tense and the past participle.

Comment: You can certainly say "hast cometh" if you want to.  No one other than your editor or English teacher is going to stop you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An additional confusion here is that the past participle of *to come* is again *come*.  In the present perfect tense, you use [*have,has,had,hast,hath*] followed by the past participle of your main verb.

Another example, where the past participle will not confuse us:
*I keep, thou keepest, he keepeth* ...  nowadays *I keep, you keep, he keeps*
but *thou hast kept* (here *kept* is the past participle of *to keep*)

Comment: So hmmm... if I wanted to say has come in an archaic way, is there any way to do that properly?

Answer (score 3):

Because *[thou] hast* is the second person singular and *[he] cometh* is the third person singular. They just don't belong together. 
Thou comest; he cometh.
Thou hast come; he hath come.

Comment: Is there an archaic form for "has come", other than "has come"? :)

Comment: @wolfdawn _Has come_ is not the archaic form at all – that would be what Kate wrote in the answer: _he hath come_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, oh yeah, thanks, that was a typo.  I meant to type hath but that is my answer.